# Reloading string in TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsurlconnection, nsdata

Alright heres the deal. I have a sports app that i want to update scores (parsed from a website) that are in a tableview when viewdidappear or when the user scrolls through the list. so basically updating the text of a label present in a cell without just putting my function in the cellForRowAtIndex making the performance awful.

I have tried to do something like loading images asynchronously in a tableview using NSURLConnection but without any luck(only one was loading into the table). I was wondering if someone has done this before and could help me.

Comment: what exaclty you want to do .display text or images?

Comment: text. i have a label on the cell that i want to update with data from the a webpage that i have parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

[Apple iOS reference library is here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
            NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section], nil];
            [(UITableView *)self.view reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths
                                            withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            [indexPaths release];
```

Comment: my issue is not with how to reload the data. it is how to get data from a website that i parsed to go into the label of the cell.

Comment: The proper way to go about this is to reload each cell individually when incoming data affects it, and have cellForRowAtIndexPath set the updated data. However, if you think reloading the whole cell uses too many resources you could use delegates or Key-Value-Observing design (make sure you remove the delegate/observer when the cell is deallocated or assigned new data - row)!

Comment: If reloading the cell uses too many resources the design of the tableview controller is wrong.